# Pairing bluetooth device with user defined PIN-QT

Tags: bluetooth, qt5

I am trying to make a bluetooth pairing application with Qt5. i want to pair with a HID device which is having default pin 1234(say), i want to enter this pin in my application.

```
     QBluetoothLocalDevice localDevice;
     localDevice.requestPairing(address, QBluetoothLocalDevice::Paired);
 connect(&localDevice, SIGNAL(pairingDisplayPinCode(QBluetoothAddress,QString)),
            this, SLOT(displayPinCode(QBluetoothAddress,QString)));
    connect(&localDevice, SIGNAL(pairingDisplayConfirmation(QBluetoothAddress,QString)),
            this, SLOT(displayParingConfirmation(QBluetoothAddress,QString)));

void BluetoothDevice::displayPinCode(const QBluetoothAddress &address, QString pin)

{

    localDevice.pairingConfirmation(true); 

}

void BluetoothDevice::displayParingConfirmation(const QBluetoothAddress &address, QString pin)

{

    localDevice.pairingConfirmation(true);


}
```

this code emit some random pin.
Is there any provision to input a pin and pair device using that pin.
thanks in advance. 
(i am using Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: have you found any document regarding this? I'm in the same boat. Thanks

Comment: @ramtheconqueror Plese check the answer , hope this will help you, All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the files listed below from [here](https://git.merproject.org/mer-core/libbluez-qt/tree/master/bluez-qt):

1. `bluetoothagentadaptor.cpp`
2. `bluetoothagentadaptor.h`
3. `bluetoothbaseagent.cpp`
4. `bluetoothbaseagent.h`

Comment: Can you please give an example or write some steps?